# Wo sind die Knaben hin?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Wie ist im deutschen Sprachraum die Verteilung des Gebrauchs der Wörter *Knabe, Junge, Bube* in Schrift- und Umgangssprache? Ein paar Dinge weiß ich bereits, aber einiges ist mir noch unklar.

Aus der deutschen Schriftsprache ist der Knabe [in den letzten fünfzig Jahren fast verschwunden](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der+Knabe%2Cder+Junge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3). Nördlich eines Gebiets, das noch  Mainz und Würzburg enthält, [dominiert der Junge auch die Umgangssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-1/f01/), während fast überall sonst der Bube vorherrscht. Wie aber sieht es in Süddeutschland in der Schriftsprache aus? Gibt es in den Lokalteilen der SZ Buben? Wie ist es in Österreich? In der NZZ habe ich Buben, aber hauptsächlich Knaben gefunden. Ist Knabe in der Schweizer Schriftsprache der bevorzugte Begriff? Hat sich der Knabe irgendwo in der Umgangssprache gehalten?

Und wie sah es vor Hundert Jahren in der Schrift- und in der Umgangssprache aus?

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das Tag *etymology* korrekt ist, mich interessiert nicht die Herkunft, sondern nur die jüngere Geschichte der Wörter.

Comment: Nur eine Kleinigkeit, aber eventuell kannst Du noch ergänzen _In Nord- **und Mittel**deutschland dominiert der Junge_

Comment: @Marzipanherz, Danke, ich gebe zu, dass weder Dresden noch Köln in Norddeutschland liegen. Andererseits weiß wohl keiner so recht, was Mitteldeutschland ist. Ich hoffe, es ist jetzt besser. Orte weiter westlich und östlich zur Abgrenzung zu benutzen, wäre besser gewesen, aber ich bin geographisch schwach und habe mich auf das beschränkt, was auf der Karte eingezeichnet war.

Comment: Die https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainlinie_(Politik) scheint ganz ähnlich zu verlaufen, und linguistisch gesehen gibt es in der Gegend auch die https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyerer_Linie_(Isoglosse) - aber die ist wohl noch weniger geläufig :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz Die Speyerer-Linie hatte ich mir angeschaut, aber sie passte nicht ganz, und ich wollte auch nicht den Anschein erwecken, dass das die gleiche Sprachgrenze ist.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: ah ja Danke - hab's nicht als solchen erkannt, wer rechnet schon mit einem Link zur (Teil-)Antwort in einer Frage... my bad

Answer (score 4):

Aus Österreich kann ich berichten, dass während der aktuellen Berichterstattung um die 12 Buben, die samt ihrem Trainer in einer Höhle in Thailand eingeschlossen waren, in allen Medien die ich wahrgenommen habe, ausschließlich von **Buben** die Rede war:

- ORF: [Acht **Buben** und Trainer noch in Höhle](http://orf.at/stories/2446121/)
- Kurier: [**Buben** in thailändischer Höhle: Baldiger Rettungsversuch möglich](https://kurier.at/chronik/welt/buben-in-thailaendischer-hoehle-mehr-als-hundert-schaechte-gebohrt/400062983)
- Der Standard: [Alle zwölf **Buben** und Trainer aus thailändischer Höhle gerettet](http://derstandard.at/2000083161983/Thailaendische-Hoehle-Letzte-Rettungsaktion-begonnen)
- Die Presse: [Thailand: Elfter **Bub** aus Höhle befreit](https://diepresse.com/home/ausland/welt/5461604/Thailand_Elfter-Bub-aus-Hoehle-befreit)

Das entspricht auch dem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch in Österreich. Der Begriff *»Jungen«* wird in Österreich mehrheitlich als deutsch wahrgenommen. (*»Deutsch«* im Sinn von: zu Deutschland gehörend.)

Nachdem Medien aus Deutschland in Österreich stark verbreitet sind (Kabelfernsehen, Zeitschriften), ist aber bereits seit längerem zu beobachten, dass der aus Deutschland importierte *Junge* bereits beginnt, den heimischen *Buben* zu verdrängen. Vor allem bei jungen Sprechern ist der *Junge* schon recht gängig, er kann sich aber derzeit noch nicht wirklich gegen den *Buben* durchsetzen, weil *»der Junge«* in Österreich noch immer hauptsächlich als das Gegenteil von *»der Alte«* verstanden wird, und nicht als das Gegenteil von *»das Mädchen«*.

Die Knaben findet man in Österreich nur noch an den Fassaden von Schulen. Auf so gut wie allen Volksschulen, die vor den 1970er-Jahren erbaut wurden, steht

> Volksschule für Knaben und Mädchen

Auf älteren Gebäuden steht manchmal auch nur ein Geschlecht (z.B. »Volksschule für Knaben«). (In Österreich gibt es keine *Grundschulen* sondern *Volksschulen* für die ersten vier Schuljahre eines Kindes.)

Eine ganz besondere Knabenschule, die weltweit bekannt ist, und die auch heute noch eine reine Knabenschule (ohne Mädchen) ist, sind die

> Wiener Sänger**knaben**

Das ist allerdings nicht nur eine Volksschule, sondern auch ein Realgymnasium, dessen Schwerpunkt bekanntermaßen auf dem Unterricht von Vokalmusik liegt.

---

**Nachtrag (Reaktion auf einen Kommentar):**

Das männliche Kind heißt nicht *Bube*, sondern *Bub* (ohne E am Ende). Der Bube existiert daneben aber auch, das ist aber eine Spielkarte im französischen Blatt. (Die entsprechende Karte im doppeldeutschen Blatt, das in Österreich bei traditionellen Kartenspielen wie z.B. *Schnapsen* weiter verbreitet ist, heißt übrigens *Unter*.)

Ein männlicher Pubertierender heißt *Bursch* (ebenfalls ohne E). Übrigen haben in Österreich weder der *Bursch* noch das *Mädl* (das umgangssprachlich in der Endsilbe ebenfalls kein E, dafür aber ein vokalisiertes L hat) eine politisch/historisch bedenkliche Konnotation. Die Nazis haben beide Wörter um je ein E angereichert, damit sie weniger bayrisch bzw. österreichisch klingen, und im gesamten *Reich* verbreitet. Dadurch haben der *Bursch**e*** und das *Mäd**e**l* im Norden noch immer einen braunen Beigeschmack, den der *Bursch* und das *Mädl* im Süden nicht haben.

Comment: Man sollte vielleicht erwähnen, daß es in Österreich nicht "der Bube" heißt, sondern "der Bub". Und dann gibts noch den "Bursche"n, den assoziiere ich aber jedenfalls eher mit der NS-Zeit (bzw. "Burschenschaften").