German word for a boy
When I was learning German at school I was taught that the word for a boy was "Knabe". Having taken it up again, I now find that the teach-yourself books tell me to use the word "Junge". Is there a difference? Is "Knabe" now obsolete, or is it used in particlar contexts or with a different nuance or meaning?

I don't know if you feel confident to use a German dictionary, but the entry https://www.dwds.de/wb/Knabe answers your question perfectly imo. The most relevant description is "veraltend", which means "in the process of becoming outdated".

@HalvarF And about 2/3 of the DWDS examples relate to the tounge-in-cheek usage around "alter Knabe", which doesn't really mean a boy.

Related, in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/46008/3237

Knabe is really obsolete and has been for long time. Its broadest usage is still in Switzerland, maybe in Austria, and sometimes still in administrative officialese.
Today, a boy is "Junge" or "Bub" in southern parts of the German language region (Southern Germany, Austria, Switzerland)

That "Knabe" is "really obsolete" for 100 years is funny for someone growing up in the "Heim für Knaben und Mädchen, deren Unterbringung aus 'äußeren' Gründen notwendig ist", Hartäckerstraße 26 (https://www.geschichtewiki.wien.gv.at/Heime_f%C3%BCr_Kinder_und_Jugendliche).

@bakunin It's sometimes useful to read more than the first sentence of an answer. And your comment fully confirms what the second sentence says: Officialese and Austria. So what?

I know that this is an imperfect tool, but 100 years seems to be exaggerated: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Knaben%2CJungen%2C+Buben+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3

I'm not sure what you guys are trying to argue. Nitpicking with numbers? Make it 50 years, does it change anything in the answer? Today's state is relatively obsolete, and that is what the question was about. In case you have exact figures (more exact than an ngram that even uses the plural for no apparent reason), please provide them in an answer.

@tofro: first off, you might consider taking critique as what it is: informed reactions to what you write, not personal attacks. If you don't want the input of others, then write a book, not here. Returning to the actual topic: "Junge" is not used at all in Austria (it is considered "piefkenesisch", as they like to call words common in Germany but not Austria) to my knowledge and "Bub" is considered informal. "Knabe" is the - perceived formal - word Austrians use. This encompasses (but is not limited to) legal jargon.  (you see, I even read your third sentence)

@bakunin I didn't see a personal attack, I saw nitpicking besides the point. BTW: I checked 10 homepages (couldn't be bothered for more) of Austrian schools and boarding schools for your claim: 6 used "Buben", 1 (Vorarlberg, so close to Germany) used "Jungen", and 3 used "Burschen" for their male pupils. None of them used "Knaben", except in historic references ("We used to be the Knabenchor..."). Even the most famous Wiener Sängerknaben who should be used to the term use "Ausbildungsangebot für Buben und Mädchen" on their homepage, so use "Buben" when not referring to choir members.

... a common impression was that most of the Austrian pages somewhat seemed to try to evade the terms for male kids (maybe really not wanting to use "Junge", "Knabe", or "Bube" for the reasons you pointed out): In a lot of places, I found something along the lines of "...die Mädchen und Schüler..."

@tofro 50 or 100 years make a large difference in language usage. If you learned a word in your first 10 years of live, you will probably use it until now. So if it is outdating since 50 years, everybody above 60 years might use it. But people, older than 110 years, will rarely raise their voice or write something, you will read. My parents used still "Knabe", but very, very rarely in everyday context.

Knabe has the connotation of someone on their knees, cp. knebeln "gag", to sub-jug-ate, if bakunin's reported experience is anything to go by. Arguably it didn't help, so we have abandoned the notion. The implications for bind-, husband and semitic ben are immense.

I sense there is some difference in the connotations: A "Knabe" is (=was) a well-behaving pupil or young boy, whereas a "Bube" is a cherry-stealing, vivid, adventurous child. For that reason the book of Ludwig Thoma is entitled "Lausbubengeschichten".
